Add "keepUpToDate=T" as parametern for reqHistoricalData() in R IBrokers
Is it possible to edit reqHistoricalData() in the R IBrokers package so that keepUpToDate=T is a parameter for that function?
I tried this but got an error:
fixInNamespace("reqHistoricalData", "IBrokers", "IBrokers::reqHistoricalData")

